# Why has 'How do I corrupt a boot sector?' been removed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

Why was the question [How do I corrupt a boot sector?](https://superuser.com/questions/897914/how-do-i-corrupt-a-boot-sector/897947) removed from this site?

It seemed to be okay to ask and already had some good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closed as too broad.

Zero score question and answers,and 2-3 days between the last answers.

Got auto deleted.